# Wcf basicHttpBinding not working in Windows 8.1 app store

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, windows-8.1

I wrote a Wcf Service and its configuration file is

```
  <system.serviceModel>    
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="securityDemo">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfDemo.EmpService"  behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:3003/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfDemo.IEmpService" bindingConfiguration="securityDemo"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This working fine for a console app or WPF app.
But when I am using same service for windows 8.1 app i am getting this exception

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Deploy a WCF service on IIS Local (because IIS Express are not so flexible), set off Anonymous Authentication and set on Windows Integrated Authentication.
- make service reference in target Win 8 app.
- before using Service proxy add a lines with identification:

  var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
  client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "windows user name";
  client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "user passw";
- call a service method
- profit

Comment: I am generating ServiceReference by Visual Studio.I tried with both self host and IIS.

Comment: I have a fault with first answer. I Forgot choose your binding in WCF and used a default. With your binding i have same error, but i found a solution and rewrite answer above.

Comment: Your answer works but i want to authenticate user using System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials .

Comment: I don't want user to type his credentials, it should automatically should pick the current user credentials from the system.

Comment: I tried to using DefaultNetworkCredentials many times and many cases, but it not worked. Seems like they are contains nothing